# Is it possible to make a parent route a 404, but the child route a specific route

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

In my **router.js** file, I have something that looks like the following

```
import EmberRouter from '@ember/routing/router';

const Router = EmberRouter.extend({});

Router.map(function () {
  this.route('index', { path: '/' });
  this.route('foo', function() {
    this.route('bar', function() {
      this.route('cat');
    });
  });

  this.route('notfound', { path: '/*path' });
});

export default Router;
```

The problem is that I want the path `/foo/bar/cat` to route to the `foo.bar.cat` route, but I don't want the paths `/foo` or `/foo/bar` to route to anything except a 404. In my case, the `foo` and `bar` routes are essentially useless. I just want the url to have 3 levels for aesthetic purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually realized what made more sense was to just avoid creating `foo` and `bar` routes and create a path for the route I wanted.

So instead of doing this in ember-cli:

`ember g route foo/bar/cat`

I just did

`ember g route cat`

And then I set the desired path in the router.

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('index', { path: '/' });
  this.route('cat', { path: '/foo/bar/cat'});
  this.route('notfound', { path: '/*path' });
});
```

That gives me the correct route for `foo/bar/cat`, but `foo` and `foo/bar` both get routed to the `notfound` route.